# Database only updates after closing and opening dialog

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have a DataGridView inside a form that displays data from a database every time I load the page like this:

```
private void LoadList(string Input)
{
    fieldsDataGridView.DataSource = null;
    List<Field> fields = new List<Field>();
    fields = fieldsData.GetAllByTaskId(Input);
    List<FieldsDGViewModel> fdgvm = new List<FieldsDGViewModel>();
    foreach (var item in fields)
    {
        var f = new FieldsDGViewModel
        {
            Id = item.Id,
            Name = item.Name,
            Order = item.Order,
            IsPrint = item.IsPrint
        };
        fdgvm.Add(f);
    }
    fdgvm = fdgvm.OrderBy(x => x.Order).ToList();
    fieldsDataGridView.DataSource = fdgvm;
    fieldsDataGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
    fieldsDataGridView.Columns["Id"].Visible = false;
    fieldsDataGridView.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);
}
```

When I double click on an entry in my list, it opens a dialog box containing a form and loads the respective details from that entry. When I save the details, the dialog box closes and in the class where my DataGridView sits, there is this FormClose function that refreshes the DataGridView.

```
private void FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    RefreshDataGrid();
    RecursiveClearInputs(this.Controls);
    fieldIdInput.Text = "";
}

private void RefreshDataGrid()
{
    var selected = programInput.SelectedValue;
    if (selected != null)
    {
        var result = programsData.Get(selected.ToString());
        if (result != null)
        {
            programIdInput.Text = result.Id;
            LoadList(result.Id);
        }
    }
    if (selected == "-1")
    {
        RecursiveClearInputs(this.Controls);
        programIdInput.Text = "";
        fieldIdInput.Text = "";
        fieldsDataGridView.DataSource = null;
    }
    fieldsDataGridView.ClearSelection();
}
```

However, I am having this issue where the only way that my DataGridView refreshes properly is if I close the main form I am on and reopen it again.

I debugged and managed to capture some results.

Image1: Directly after the Update form is closed. In the fields list, only one entry can have IsPrint = true. However the image shows that both are true.

[image]

Image2: After I close and reopen the page containing the DataGridView, it shows this correct result. Only 1 IsPrint = true.

[image]

I have tried many methods to solve this issue but I'm not sure why its not refreshing properly.

This is how I open a dialog

```
EditFields editFields = new EditFields(programIdInput.Text, fieldIdInput.Text, false);
editFields.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(FormClosed);
editFields.ShowDialog();
```

EDIT:

I added a dialogresult check but it still doesn't update the datagridview properly. Maybe its a thread issue?

```
dr = editFields.ShowDialog();
if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
{
    RefreshDataGrid();
    RecursiveClearInputs(this.Controls);
    fieldIdInput.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: can you show the code of the onclick event where you open the dialog box?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just assuming how the OnCklick event looks where you open your Dialog, but I think the problem is that you try to refresh the Datagrid form another Form / Thread. (which will not work)

I suggest you open the dialog form by using ShowDialog and refresh the grid after the Form was closed in the onclick event itself. Try replacing

```
RefreshDataGrid();
```

in your FormClosed event with

```
DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
```

Then you are able to handle the grid reloading in your onclick event like this:

```
 EditFields editFields = new EditFields(programIdInput.Text, fieldIdInput.Text, false);

   if (editFields.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
   {
          RefreshDataGrid();
   }
   else
   {
     //it was canceled
   }
   editFields.Dispose();
```

Comment: I tried this method in my edit but it didn't work. I think I'm still on another thread?

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass the main form to the detail form.
In the detail form, implement the `OnClosing` or `OnClosed` event and call `MainForm.LoadList()`.

Comment: This is just one way to do it. Furthermore not even necessary depending on how the dialog was opened in the first place.

Comment: May I ask why would this be necessary? I am currently already setting an event handler for when the form closes

Comment: I have tried this method as well but it didn't work.